# MS Access SQL join two tables

Tags: sql, ms-access, join

How can I join data from the two SQL statements in MS Access so that they appear as one table:

First data table

```
Select 
    W.[Local municipality] as Munic, 
    count(W.[Settlement Name]) 
from 
    tblSett as W
where 
    W.[Water] = 'Yes'
group by 
    W.[local municipality];
```

Second data table

```
Select 
    LM.Province, LM.[Local municipality], 
    count(LM.[Local Municipality]) as [Count], 
    sum(LM.Households) as TotalHouseholds 
from 
    tblSett AS LM
group by 
    LM.Province, LM.[Local Municipality]
order by 
    LM.Province;
```

I tried the following but it shows the the total count of everything and not broken down per [Local municipality]:

```
Select 
    LM.Province, LM.[Local municipality], 
    count(LM.[Local Municipality]) as [Count], 
    sum(LM.Households) as TotalHouseholds, 
    (Select count(W.[Settlement Name] as [Count2]) 
     from tblSett as W
     where W.[Water] = 'Yes') 
from 
    tblSett AS LM
group by 
    LM.Province, LM.[Local Municipality]
order by 
    LM.Province;
```

Comment: Edit question to show sample data and desired output.

Comment: If you group by `LM.[Local Municipality]` that does not seem unexpected. Please read [this](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for some tips on improving your question.

Comment: **T-SQL** is the Transact-SQL dialect used by Sybase and SQL Server - but **not** in MS Access

Answer (score 0):

Like this, perhaps:

```
Select 
    LM.Province, 
    LM.[Local municipality] As Munic, 
    count(*) as [Count],
    sum(abs([Water] = "yes")) As WaterCount,
    sum(LM.Households) as TotalHouseholds 
From 
    tblSett AS LM
group by 
    LM.Province, 
    LM.[Local Municipality]
```

But your two queries have different groupings, so you may have to adjust, but you can see how to create the WaterCount.

Comment: Thanks Gustav. You make it look so easy, not sure how I missed it.